# How to limit characters for created tags in select in antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an antd select and I would like to limit number of characters for newly created tags inside of select element. I have prepared demo in codesandbox.

Simply I would like to forbid creating too long tags by users.

On change event `value` only shows the created tags.
The tags in application will be loaded from API in sanbox I have just hardcoded them.

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tags-max-length-dh28f

Container with onChange

```js
export const TagsInputContainer = ({ value, onChange }: ContainerProps) => {
  console.log("value in Container", value);
  const tagsfromAPI = [{ tag: "test" }, { tag: "sport" }, { tag: "education" }];
  const handleChange = (value: any) => {
    if (value) {
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TagsInput
      loading={false}
      error={false}
      tags={tagsfromAPI}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};
```

TagsInput

```js
export const TagsInput = ({ tags, onChange }: Props) => {
  const { Option } = Select;
  let children: Array<ReactNode> = [];
  if (tags) {
    children = tags.map((tag: { tag: string }, idx: number) => {
      return (
        <Option value={tag.tag} key={idx}>
          {tag.tag}
        </Option>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <Styled.TagsSelect
      placeholder="Dodaj tagi"
      mode="tags"
      onChange={onChange}
      maxTagTextLength={INPUT_VALIDATE.tagCharMax}
    >
      {children}
    </Styled.TagsSelect>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I should have some if statement inside of `map` in `TagsInput`?

Comment: Yes exactly, user can type as many as possible, but after enter it should be validated if length of that newly created tag is correct, if not I would like to place some error message below the input.

Comment: got it now. maybe you can handle it on `handleChange` function inside `TagsInputContainer` . you can check if all of the entered values are shorted than your desired lenght. (like : https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tags-max-length-forked-tkch1?file=/src/TagsInputContainer.tsx) . but there is alot more to do. you should bind only the valid tags to the `tags` parameter. also you should somehow try to bind the value of the autoselect input, so you can delete the long stuffs from there as well. (not that this fiddle is just a buggy code, but it'll give you the idea.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all big thanks for Yaya, but I have come up with another solution.Since I'm using React Hook Form I can simply validate tags using their `validate function`

```js
<Controller
        as={
          <TagsInputContainer
            validationError={errors.tags}
            errorText={t('addEntry.tagError')}
            name="tags"
            label={t('addEntry.tags')}
          />
        }
        control={control}
        type="text"
        name="tags"
        rules={{
          validate: (value: string[]) => {
            return validateTags(value);
          },
        }}
      />
```

Where validate tags function looks like this

```js
export const isValidTag = (tag: string) => {
  return tag.length < INPUT_VALIDATE.tagCharMax;
};

export const validateTags = (tags: string[]) => {
  if (tags.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return tags.every(isValidTag);
};
```